# cannot undeploy and deploy web app in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

When I stop and undeploy the old verstion and tried to deploy a new one using tomcat manager, the message shows ok but the app didn't show up in the application list. Then I delete the war file and directory in both webapps and work directory, and deploy again, it still the case. I google it but cannot find a useful answer. So I can only deploy war file with different name now. Any one can help?

Comment: What error message do you get when you deploy again? What do logs in catalina.out say?

Comment: just said the file already existed. I think the problem is I didn't delete the servlet source file in src directory. After delete the java file it works. But I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Stop an application before undeployment. It helped me.